# Android: can I protect an app portion with a signature-level permission that is defined in another app with a different signature?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Let's assume that the Android app `App1` declares the following permission:

```
<permission android:name="unipd.elia.delta.DELTA_SERVICE_MANAGER"
    android:description="@string/startDeltaServicePermission_description"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Obviously, this declaration means that only other apps signed with the same key as `App1` can **use** (acquire) that permission.

However, my question is this: can another app `App2`, which is signed with a **different** key than `App1`, **protect a portion of itself with that permission**? In other words, can `App2` do this:

```
<service android:name=".DeltaLoggingService" android:process=":remote" android:exported="true"
        android:permission="unipd.elia.delta.DELTA_SERVICE_MANAGER" />
```

even if `App2` was not signed with the same key as `App1`?

EDIT: In case ayone is interested, the real-world scenario is this: `App1` can interact with other apps that act as plugins for it, and I want to allow third parties to develop new plugins which can be used by `App1`. However, I don't want apps other than App1 (or any app not developed by me) to interact with such plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while waiting for the answer I had time to test myself and yes, it works.